# Putting extra space between keyboard and textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, textfield

I have a button stick to the bottom in a flutter app view which has some textfields inside a scrollable list-view. So when the onscreen keyboard opens because of tapping on a textfield the button stays stick to the keyboard, which is the expected behaviour. Now the problem is the portion of the textfield get hidden behind the button view. If I hide the button it works fine as there have to button view to hide the textfield. It seems the problem is the flutter framework is not considering the height of the button in addition to the onscreen keyboard height.

Therefore, my question is, have there any way to add the button height with the on screen keyboard height, thus while showing the keyboard the auto scrolling to keep the textfield visible consider both the onscreen keyboard and the button height?

Or have there any way to add some extra space between the keyboard and textfield? I already tried adding sizedbox with the height of the button at the end of the list-view, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you sticking the button to the bottom?

Comment: @flutter using stack and allign

Comment: Are you using a scaffold? And is it part of the body property?

Comment: yes, there have scaffold, can't share the code, as the view is part of a very deep tree

Comment: you could try and put the button in the BottonNav property of the scaffold

Comment: have there any other way, it could break other things, as I didn't add the button in the codebase.

Comment: place whole view in SingleChildScrollView...when keyboard open you view will shift

Comment: if this fails please paste you code and screenshot of view expected behaviour so that community can help you better